# Method of Steepest Descent and Lagrange

Tags: calculus, optimization, numerical-methods

I am totally stumped for what to do here, any help would be appreciated.

1) What happens if you apply the method of steepest descent to $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$?

2)Lagrange multipliers method- Find the dimensions of the rectangular box open at the top of greatest internal volume, given the surface area of the five faces is $108 \, \mathbb{cm}^2$.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using steepest descent to minimize $f$? What happened?

Comment: @littleO I am unsure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the second question, calling $l,w,h$ the dimensions of the box, you have $$V= l\times w \times h$$ and the  surface area of the five faces is given by $$A=l\times w +2l\times h +2w\times h $$ So, using Lagrange multipliers, you look for the extremum of $$F=lwh+\lambda(lw+2lh+2wh-108)$$ As usual, compute the partial derivatives and set them equal to $0$ $$F'_l=hw+\lambda  (2 h+w)=0\tag 1$$ $$F'_w=h l+\lambda  (2 h+l)=0\tag 2$$ $$F'_h=lw+\lambda  (2 l+2 w)=0\tag 3$$ $$F'_\lambda=lw+2lh+2wh-108=0\tag 4$$ Comapring $(1)$ and $(2)$, it is clear (I hope) that $w=l$. Using $(1)$ we then get $$l=w=-\frac{2 h \lambda }{h+\lambda }$$ Replacing in $(3)$ yiels to $$F'_h=\frac{4 h^2 \lambda ^2}{(h+\lambda )^2}-\frac{8 h \lambda ^2}{h+\lambda }=-\frac{4 h \lambda ^2 (h+2 \lambda )}{(h+\lambda )^2}=0$$ So $h=-2\lambda$ and then $l=w=-4\lambda$. Now, using $(4)$ $$48 \lambda ^2-108=0 \implies \lambda=\pm \frac 32$$ but, since in our world at least, the dimensions must be positive then $\lambda=- \frac 32$.

I hope and wish that this clarifies how the problem can be approached.

You should notice that the given value for the surface area only appears in $(4)$. Doing exactly the same for $A=a$, you should arrive to $$\lambda=-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{4 \sqrt{3}}$$ and then the corresponding dimensions.